# How to check if a property is available in the Model in Razor Template?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-web-api

I want to check in a razor template if a certain property is available in the Model.

Can you please tell me how I can do that?, I am using the below code:

```
if (Model.objectIds !=null)
```

When I am doing this I am getting an exception:

```
"'RazorEngine.Compilation.RazorDynamicObject' does not contain a definition for 'objectIds'"
```

Comment: Can you post the code that creates said Model? and the code for the view? My guess is that you do not have the Model you think you have.

Answer (score 12):

You can try this in you razor view:

```
if (Model.GetType().GetProperty("objectIds") != null)
```